# How can I get the district of a selected city in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

```
  List<String> cities = [];
  List<String> districts = [];
  String selectedCity = '';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fetchCities();
  }

  Future<void> fetchCities() async {
    var response =
        await http.get(Uri.parse('https://turkiyeapi.dev/api/v1/provinces'));

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final List<dynamic> cityData = json.decode(response.body)["data"];

      List<String> cityNames =
          cityData.map((city) => city['name'].toString()).toList();

      setState(() {
        cities = cityNames;
      });
    } else {
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print(response.reasonPhrase);
      }
    }
  }

  Future<void> fetchDistricts(String selectedCity) async {
    var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(
        'https://turkiyeapi.dev/api/v1/provinces?name=$selectedCity'));

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final List<dynamic> districtData = json.decode(response.body)["data"];

      List<String> districtNames =
          districtData.map((district) => district['name'].toString()).toList();

      setState(() {
        districts = districtNames;
      });
    } else {
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print(response.reasonPhrase);
      }
    }
  }

  void onCitySelected(String selectedCity) async {
    setState(() {
      this.selectedCity = selectedCity;
      print(selectedCity);
    });
    await fetchDistricts(selectedCity);
  }
```

There are two functions here where I try to see the cities of Turkey and the districts of the selected city.

Here is the link [**where I got the API**](https://turkiyeapi.cyclic.app/)

No matter what I do, I cannot get the districts of the selected city. I either display all counties in the country or just the selected city.

```
ListView.builder(
                itemCount: cities.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return ListTile(
                    visualDensity:
                        const VisualDensity(
                            horizontal: 0,
                            vertical: -4),
                    title: Text(
                      cities[index],
                      textAlign:
                          TextAlign.center,
                      style: bioProvinces,
                    ),
                    onTap: () {
                      _selectedCityController
                          .text = cities[index];
                      onCitySelected(
                          cities[index]);
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                    },
                  );
                },
              ),
```

Here I show the cities and after selecting the city I call the `onCitySelected` function.

```
ListView.builder(
                itemCount: districts.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return ListTile(
                    visualDensity:
                        const VisualDensity(
                            horizontal: 0,
                            vertical: -4),
                    title: Text(
                      districts[index],
                      textAlign:
                          TextAlign.center,
                      style: bioProvinces,
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
```

I'm trying to show the districts here too.

Comment: can you add a full working sample? I'm not sure why you are calling " Navigator.pop(context);"

Answer (score 0):

`https://turkiyeapi.dev/api/v1/provinces?name=$selectedCity'`

The endpoint which you are using will fetch provinces again. It won't fetch districts specifically for you i.e. You are getting the same JSON as of the API call in the city function.
So technically, you don't need to fetch districts separately. If you want to get the district of a selected city, you can just filter them out from the cities json. This you can achieve by setting your cities parsed JSON as state and using them in onCitySelected Function.

It would look something like this:

```
   List<dynamic> cityData = [];
   List<String> cities = [];
   List<String> districts = [];
    
    Future<void> fetchCities() async {
        var response =
            await Uri.http.get(Uri.parse('https://turkiyeapi.dev/api/v1/provinces'));
    
        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
          final List<dynamic> citiesData = json.decode(response.body)["data"];
    
          List<String> cityNames =
              cityData.map((city) => city['name'].toString()).toList();
    
          setState(() {
            cities = cityNames;
            cityData=citiesData;
          });
        } else {
          if (kDebugMode) {
            print(response.reasonPhrase);
          }
        }
      }
    
      void onCitySelected(String selectedCity) async {
        final city = cityData.firstWhere((city)=>city['name']==selectedCity);
        if(city!=null) {
          final districtsData = city["districts"];
          if(districtsData!=null) {
          final districtNames = districtsData.map((district) =>district['name'].toString()).toList();     
            setState(() {
              districts = districtNames;
            });
          }
        }
      }
```

Also, an additional point you should use id of the city instead of name since you can end up with errors if the city names are same.

Comment: How should ı describe the citiesData?

Comment: Also, for values ​​such as name and districts, "The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'int'." I get an error.

Comment: Hey, I have edited the answer. So, now you have a  cityData as a state variable. Then, initially, you fetch the cities and set the cityData and cities state. Now, when you select a city, you will filter the cityData response to get the districts of the selected city. Here, instead of using cities array, in the ListView.builder you can directly use cityData array and set the city's id as the key of ListView item. Now, on Select you can get the particular id of the city from cityData using index, then in the onCitySelected you can use that id. This way you can avoid filter using name.